# Google Container Registry - max image size?

Tags: google-container-registry

Tried googling and reading their documentation, but I cannot find what is the larges image size they support? I have an 15.7GB image, and I cannot upload it to Container registry:

```
gcloud docker -- push eu.gcr.io/XXXXXX/YYYYYY:ZZZZZZ
The push refers to a repository [eu.gcr.io/XXXXXX/YYYYYY]
5efa92011d99: Retrying in 1 second
8bac40556b9d: Retrying in 8 seconds
e4990dfff478: Retrying in 14 seconds
9f8566ee5135: Retrying in 10 seconds
unknown: Bad Request.
```

Answer (score 2):

Please contact us with the un-redacted image at gcr-contact@google.com

In general (this may not be an issue for you), the problem with large images is that the short-lived access tokens you receive via our normal token exchange will result in failed uploads. You're going to have to explore JSON key authentication in order to enable those very long sessions when uploading your images to GCS: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication